# How to find the sin angle for a double value?

Tags: java, math

How do you go about finding the sin angle for a value?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at [`Math`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) API?

Comment: Math.sin? Did you try searching it before?

Comment: Yes. Like for example sin30 = 0.5 How do I get the the 30* on entering that 0.5 or the angle for anyother value I enter?

Comment: You understand that trig functions, unless otherwise designated, deal in radians, not degrees, right?

Answer (score 3):

here is an example of use of `Math.asin()`:

```
public class Test{ 

   public static void main(String args[]){
     double degrees = 45.0;
     double radians = Math.toRadians(degrees);

     System.out.format("The value of pi is %.4f%n", Math.PI);
     System.out.format("The arcsine of %.4f is %.4f degrees %n",
                     Math.sin(radians),
                     Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(Math.sin(radians))));


   }
}
```